# Prevent pressing the alt hotkey from focusing menu in Gtk 3

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gtk, gtk3

The behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd> changed in a subtle manner between `gtk2` and `gtk3`. In `gtk2`, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> then releasing it did nothing. In `gtk3`, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> then releasing it focuses the first item of the first menu (usually, File > New).

Is there any hidden setting that reverts the `gtk2` behavior?

Comment: My guess is recompiling without the option... :/